# To have syntax highlighting for codes in LaTex

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I would like to know **how you can syntax highlighting in a LaTex document for codes**.

An example of such a document is [this guide about a Python library and Page 9](https://web.archive.org/web/20090806223338/https://beaker.groovie.org/beaker.pdf).

Perhaps, the document is not built by LaTex. Perhaps, by Markdown and with some addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you can look at Prettify.  You might be able to create a custom CSS file for LaTeX and get Prettify set up for it...

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

I use this plug-in on my website:
http://rsolberg.com/ViewBlog/2

StackOverflow also uses it!

Answer (score 3):

The [listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) package is one way to include syntax-highlighted source code listings in a LaTeX document.  For other options, see [the relevant entry in the TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=codelist).

Comment: listings unfortunately has several shortcomings in that it only highlights what it thinks might be nice to highlight instead of having a grammar for the languages. It does weird things on floating point numbers in exponential notation, for example. That being said, I don't know a better replacement, sadly.